# How to set up 301 redirect for URL with question mark

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have encountered some issue with 301 redirect and htaccess file.

I need to redirect the following url:

```
http://www.domain.com/?specifications=colours/page/3
```

to:

```
http://www.domain.com/colours
```

The 301 redirect command I wrote in htaccess file is as follow:

```
Redirect 301 /?specifications=colours/page/3 http://domain.com/colours
```

And it doesn't work at the moment. What is the correct way to set up 301 redirect here?

Your help will be sincerely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) is only for simple cases

> mod_alias is designed to handle simple URL manipulation tasks. For more complicated tasks such as manipulating the query string, use the tools provided by mod_rewrite.

For your case, you must extract the part from the query string and append that to your root URL

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} specifications=(.+?)/
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/%1 [R,L]
```

This redirects all accesses to the root URL with a query string of `specifications=something/` to `http://www.domain.com/something`